# My cats hair is balding after I showered her with human shampoo

Tags: cats, skin-condition, bathing, hairloss

I bathed my cat with human shampoo because she got stuck in rat glue and I had no idea how to remove it. I rubbed her with vegetable oil based on what google said to use and it came off but then after I bathed her with human shampoo her skin was a little spiky after she dried. So I gave her another shower except this time with gain dish soap because I realized human shampoo isn’t good at all for her skin. And now her hair is slowly balding in certain spots and I have brushed her multiple times to remove dead hair and help her blood flow. I put some coconut oil on her bald spots. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Please stop using home remedies and "Google-Fu" and talk to a vet.

Comment: First of all, stop washing your cat. I do understand why you bathed her the first time, but every bath adds more damage because it drys the skin out even more.

Comment: People who use rat glue also tend to use rat poison. Some rat poisons might cause hair loss. If you *ever* used a rat poison, even sometime in distant past, make sure to tell the vet about it. There js nothing we can do here.

Comment: The best advice I can give you in this case is to A) let a vet have a look at her and find out what exactly caused the hair loss or B) feed your cat special cat food or food supplements for a better coat and hope that it improves in the next 2 weeks. These special foods or supplements usually contain more oil than other foods, which is supposed to replenish the skin oil (that was destroyed by bathing) from the inside.

Comment: @Manuki unless you are trained and have the proper equipment, attempting to cut a cat's fur by yourself is not a good idea, either. Cats have fragile skin and don't tend to hold still when you come at them with a clipper or scissors, making it very easy to accidentally injure them.